# Why two instances of same app get installed after copiling the Linphone code (android)

Tags: android, linphone

I am working on Linphone-Android, I have changed the package name following the steps are mentioned in the Readme file. There was not any problem till here.

I just wondor why two instance Linphone Icon appear on my phone and emulator,
When I uninstall one of them they both get uninstall and the app completely removed on my phone.

Please let me know if any extra information is needed,

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the manifest file. may be you kept 2 activities as launcher acitivity.